# Bash - How to word if then statement

Tags: shell, syntax-error, token, pseudocode

I'm attempting to append to a file this pseudo code:

```
 if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]; then.
```

I did it on shell as:

```
 echo if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]; then
```

But it gives me a syntax error near unexpected token 'then'. I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Er. Remove the `echo`?

Comment: remove then in the echo line to see what it prints

Comment: In general, use `$(...)` instead of backquotes, and use `$(( $MOD % 5 ))` instead of the `expr` command. `echo 'if [ $(( $MOD % 5 )) -eq 0 ]; then '`.

Comment: Or even `if (( MOD % 5 == 0 )); then` is even more readable. Ref [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) in the manual

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes:

```
$ echo 'if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]; then'
if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this right, you are trying to append this actual text to a file?

```
if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]; then
```

Then the issue is your command structure. You used this:

```
echo if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]; then
```

This is actually two commands as far as the shell is concerned, due to the semicolon. So it is the same as:

```
echo if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]
then
```

Since `then` is not normally a valid command, and this is outside the context of a shell conditional (for instance `if`), the shell doesn't know what to do with it.

What you need to do is quote the entire thing as a string and pass *that* to echo.

```
echo 'if [ `expr $MOD % 5` -eq 0 ]; then'
```

Using single quote (`'`) rather than double quote (`"`) is important. If you use double quote, then the bit in backticks (`expr $MOD % 5`) would be evaluated instead of passed to the file as-is.